# arcpy cannot extract a subdataset from a .3D file

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, gdal, error-000840, grib-2

I am working with data which represents the atmosphere as rasters at 29 different altitudes. This data is stored in a ".3D" file. When I drag and drop into ArcMap it asks me to select the layer I want. When I use arcpy's "extractsubdataset" tool it says "ERROR 000840 The value is not a raster layer". I'm pretty sure it is because the tool only accepts ".HDF" and ".NITF". Is there any other way to automatically extract the data?

I need to extract over 100 subdatasets from over 100 ".3D" files so I can't do it manually. If I do multiple subdatasets at the same time from drag and drop they all get the same name and it is hard to distinguish them apart.

The data is the National Centers for Environmental Prediction North American Regional Reanalysis

Not sure if I am allowed to have links, but here is a link to the data: https://rda.ucar.edu/datasets/ds608.0/index.html#cgi-bin/transform?xml=/datasets/ds608.0/metadata/wfmd/3HRLY%252017%25NARR3D_201708_1012.tar.GrML

For syntax I have the input and output as strings to where the file is located and the subset index as an int.
arcpy.ExtractSubDataset_management(filepath,outputfolder+"test.tif",1)

Does GDAL work? If it does I can get IT to install it on my workstation (I've never used GDAL).

Answer (score 1):

I just found a solution for anyone else who comes across this issue. Simply change the file name to be .hdf (do it on a copy first to make sure it works for you). Then it should work perfectly